# How can I get rid of an error that says "ByteArray Objects Cannot be Converted to Strings" in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, coldfusion

I am using the following code to `POST` XML data to a remote server.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Transmission t)
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
    ViewBag.OtherMessage = "";
    ViewBag.ResponseHtml = "";

    try
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transmission));
        XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); ns.Add("", "");
        xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true; //omit the xml declaration line
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xws);
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, t, ns);
            var contentData = sw.ToString();
            var httpContent = new StringContent(contentData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("theUrl", httpContent);
            ViewBag.ResponseHtml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return View("Error"); //TODO: change this to success when I get the 500 error fixed
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

The response that I am getting is saying "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings." I haven't been given many details about the system to which I am posting this data, only that it using Adobe ColdFusion (which I know next to nothing about). Is there something that I can do on my side to fix this problem?

**Edit**

The response HTML I am getting is this:

```
<head> 
<title>Error Occurred While Processing Request</title> 
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    function showHide(targetName) { 
      if( document.getElementById ) { 
        // NS6+ 
        target = document.getElementById(targetName); 
      } else if( document.all ) { 
        // IE4+ 
        target = document.all[targetName]; 
      } 
      if( target ) { 
        if( target.style.display == "none" ) { 
          target.style.display = "inline"; 
        } else { 
          target.style.display = "none"; 
        } 
      } 
    } 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 16pt/18pt verdana"> 
    The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
    <br> 
    Please contact the website administrator. 
</font> 
<br><br> 
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#000808" bgcolor="#e7e7e7"> 
<tr> 
    <td bgcolor="#000066"> 
        <font style="COLOR: white; FONT: 11pt/13pt verdana" color="white"> 
            The following information is meant for the website developer 
            for debugging purposes. 
        </font> 
    </td> 
<tr> 
<tr> 
    <td bgcolor="#4646EE"> 
        <font style="COLOR: white; FONT: 11pt/13pt verdana" color="white"> 
            Error Occurred While Processing Request 
        </font> 
    </td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td> 
        <font style="COLOR: black; FONT: 8pt/11pt verdana"> 
            <table width="500" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
                <tr> 
                    <td id="tableProps2" align="left" valign="middle" width="500"> 
                    <h1 id="textSection1" style="COLOR: black; FONT: 13pt/15pt verdana"> 
                            ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings. 
                        </h1> 
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
                .... A BUNCH OF OTHER CF DEBUG TEXT ....
```

Comment: Please post the entire exception stack so we can help you.

Comment: @JuanR Thanks for responding. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the ColdFusion administrator, as it is on machine that belongs a third party company that, so far, has been completely unreliable in getting me any information. I was just wondering if there was a way to change the code that I have written so that this error doesn't happen.

Comment: I am talking about YOUR code. Is the code throwing an error? IS the `catch` block being executed? Where does it break? Does it break at all? Are you seeing the error returned as a string? Please be more specific.

Comment: "ByteArray objects....." is a CF error message. It sounds like it may be an issue in the ColdFusion code that's trying to return to you. It's not properly converting what should be a string value before trying to send it back as a string. If that's the case, it may not be an issue you can handle with your code. They'll have to fix it. I agree that you need to try to get access to more of the error info.

Comment: @JuanR My code is not breaking. The catch block is not executing. No errors are being thrown. The response that I'm getting from the server says "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings."  It is giving me this message in HTML, which I am parsing in my view. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's OK. Problem solved. The error is happening at the server. You are only seeing the response. Can you post the full response string then? (remove any sensitive information).

Comment: @JuanR Yes. I am posting it now. It's just HTML, but maybe it will help us determine the issue.

Comment: @JuanR StackOverflow parsed the HTML string, but you get the point. This is the response I'm getting.

Comment: That is some very old code you're hitting.

Comment: The response says it all: "The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.<br> Please contact the website administrator.". Contact them again and tell them the page is breaking. They need to fix this on their end.

Comment: @JuanR That is what I was afraid of. Thanks for your help. It's always good to bounce this stuff of someone else, if not for any other reason than to keep your own sanity intact. Thank you as well, Shawn.

Comment: I had forgotten how bad Macromedia's CF Error Message HTML was. This is definitely an error on the provider's end that they will likely need to work with you to fix. My guess is that they are working with such an old version of CF (possibly MX), that it doesn't know how to correctly parse your XML. Regardless, it looks like 1) they need more robust error reporting turned on to see more of what's breaking and 2) they should be trapping/logging this error and not sending so much info back in their response.